# How to parse a request with multiple params in express

Tags: node.js, express

How can I parse a query like this using express

```
https://www.tutoret.com/api/user/loginportal=desktop&username=yohannes&password=195211185d416effacb5c6a4b43d8172753739228c396929911215027d4dbc0d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

const username = req.query.username;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.query` to get querystring.

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {

    // Access the provided query parameters
    let loginportal = req.query.loginportal;
    let username= req.query.username;
    let password= req.query.password;

    res.send({loginportal : loginportal, username: username});
});
```